# How to map pixel or point units to ffmpeg font / text size

Tags: css, ffmpeg, pixel, points, units-of-measurement

I have a web page form where I take text size in pixel or point units pass to ffmpeg and run ffmpeg command to set text size but they don't match. what is the ffmpeg text size standard unit or is there any way I can convert pixels or units into ffmpeg text size so they don't differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fontsize parameter in drawtext filter is passed onto the freetype library which is actually responsible for drawing the characters. The closest you can come to mapping the fontsize to pixel units using the ffmpeg runtime is to print

```
ffmpeg -v 24 -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color -vf "drawtext=/path/to/font:fontsize=1000:text='A':x=W/2:y=print(th\,24)" -vframes 1 -f null -
```

This will print the height, in pixels, that the uppercase 'A' occupies for a fontsize of 1000 using the specified font. Different fonts have different scales.

Comment: What should i do when I'm already using x,y to position the text here is the full (php) cmd: 
'drawtext="fontfile=\''.$txtfont.'\': text=\''.$txtline.'\':\x='.$posx.': y=('.($result_y_ratio*146.938).'-text_h)/2: fontsize='.$txtsize.': fontcolor='.$txtclr.':shadowcolor=#777777@0.5:shadowx=4:shadowy=4"'

Comment: Run this command once to get points to pixel ratio for desired font and then set points for actual required size. e.g. if fontsize 1000 produces a reading of 720. Then to get a 100 pixel tall drawing, set size to (1000/720)*100 = `138.88`

Comment: The problem solved by multiplying the results ((1000/720)*100) with a range of 1.5 to 2.5 for different fonts, Thanks!